# Django: Formset just saves the first form

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have a Formset that allow so uploadoad multiple images with a description:

```
def bilddokumentation_form(request, auftrag):

    auftrag = Auftrag.objects.get(id=auftrag)

    BilddokumentationFormSet = formset_factory(BilddokumentationForm, extra=1)

    formset = BilddokumentationFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            name = form['name']
            bild = form['bild']
            Bilddokumentation.objects.create(
                name=name,
                bild=bild,
                auftrag=auftrag,
                user=request.META['USER'],
            )
    else:
        print(formset.errors)

    return render(request, 'auftragsverwaltung/bilddokumentation_add.html', {'item_forms': formset, 'auftrag': auftrag})
```

But only the first form will be saved. The second form doesn't appear in the `cleaned_data`.

This is the template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template">
<div id="item-__prefix__">
    {{ item_forms.empty_form }}
</div>
</script>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ item_forms.management_form }}
<div id="items-form-container">
    {% for item_form in item_forms %}
        <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            {{ item_form.id }}
            {{ item_form.as_p }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<a href="#" id="add-item-button" class="btn btn-info add-item">weiteres Bild hinzufügen</a>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Bilder hinzufügen">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var count = $('#items-form-container').children().length;
        var tmplMarkup = $('#item-template').html();
        var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
        $('div#items-form-container').append(compiledTmpl);

        // update form count
        $('#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count+1);

        // some animate to scroll to view our new form
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#add-item-button").position().top-200
            }, 800);
    });
});
</script>
```

And the form:

```
class BilddokumentationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bilddokumentation
        exclude = ['user', 'datum', 'auftrag']
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea,
        }
```

I can see that the second form is in the `POST` data, but it wont appear in the `cleaned_data`.

What would be the correct way to do it? And why does Django discard the second form?

Comment: If this is an `ModelForm` why are you using `formset_factory` instead of `modelformset_factory` or `inlineformset_factory`?

Comment: Little offtopic: instead of request.META['USER'] just use request.user

Comment: No particular reason - I tried with modelformset_factory, but it has the same result. If I add another form via JS it will just add the first - even though it is in the POST

Comment: Can you verify that `#id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS` is getting updated correctly by your JS? Is the right value for that field in the POST data?

Comment: Also, you usually iterate over `formset.forms` and access `cleaned_data` on each resulting form, rather than iterating over `formset.cleaned_data`. Does that help?

Comment: @DanielRoseman #id_item_items-TOTAL_FORMS didn't got updated correctly - thx!